# PHP: Issue combining sub-arrays into new array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop, array-merge

Working on a poll script, but I have little problems with the options of a poll, creating a new array of it.

The actual example array contains 3 sub-arrays with options, sum of votes and percentage:

```
Array
        (
            [poll_options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Good
                    [1] => Bad
                    [2] => I do not care
                )

            [poll_answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [poll_percentage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 20
                )

        )
```

Now I need to create a new array of the values, the result must be like this:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Good
                    [answers] => 3
                    [percentage] => 60
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Bad
                    [answers] => 1
                    [percentage] => 20
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [option] => I do not care
                    [answers] => 1
                    [percentage] => 20
                )

        )
```

Whatever tried so far, I just can't reach this result I want.
Any ideas?

Comment: what u try , post the code ! 10x

Comment: @HaimEvgi: posting everything I tried today already and I would hit the maximum allowed characters of a question. I think for this question it is not needed to post more code as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach (array_keys($old_array['poll_options']) as $i) {
    $new_array[] = array(
        'option' => $old_array['poll_options'][$i],
        'answers' => $old_array['poll_answers'][$i],
        'percentage' => $old_array['poll_percentage'][$i]
    );
}
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/83175)

Comment: That's it I think. Let me test it quickly.

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you Barmer, I will mark this as correct answer in 3 minutes when I may to do so!

Comment: What part of this trivial loop was so difficult?

Comment: I just totally forgot about 'array_keys()', was always stuck with 'array_merge()'. I'm getting old... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray=Array();
$count=count($array["poll_oprions"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $newElem=Array(); 
    $newElem["option"]=$array["poll_option"][$i];
    $newElem["answers"]=$array["poll_answers"][$i];
    $newElem["percentage"]=$array["poll_percentage"][$i];
    $newArray[]=$newElem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column):

```
$new_array = array();
$new_array[] = array(
    'option' => array_column($old_array, 0),
    'answers' => array_column($old_array, 1),
    'percentage' => array_column($old_array, 2),
);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83178)

Note that this function is => PHP 5.5.0. If you're using an older version of PHP, you can use the implementation written in plain PHP (by the author of this function). It's [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).